# Can you draw a circle on a mapbox static map?

Tags: mapbox

I have some geojson shapes I'm passing to the [Mapbox static maps API](https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/static/). Some of the shapes are polylines, others are circles represented as points with a radius property e.g:

```
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "radius": 500
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                30.5,
                50.5
            ]
        }
    }
```

These get rendered as points with a marker. Is there any way I can get a point to render as a circle of a certain radius centered around that point?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use layer type : circle to display the points as circles. You can then use expressions to get the radius from your geojson properties:
Check the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awcvr6jx/1/)

```
map.addLayer({
            'id': 'demo',
            'type': 'circle',
            'source': 'points',
            'paint': {
              // use get expression to get the radius property. Divided by 10 to be able to display it
                'circle-radius': ['/',['get', 'radius'],10],
                'circle-color': "blue"
            }
        });
```

Comment: The question is about the static maps API

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper way to do this would be for mapbox to support passing geojson to the `addlayer` querystring param of the static image. However, at this time, they seem to only allow you to use an existing mapbox source for static image layers.

My personal workaround was to create a circle image with a transparent background, upload it to the web, and reference as an overlay at the coordinates that I want to display it at. The format is `url-{url}({lon},{lat})` and would be used like this:

```
const overlay = `url-${circleURL}(${lon},${lat})`
...
const url = `https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/${style}/static/${overlay}/${lon},${lat},${zoom},${pitch}/${size}@2x?access_token=${token}`
```

It's not ideal, but it works for my use-case. Make sure the URL is urlencoded.

Comment: how do you create he circles images of the determined radius? for example 100meters? and if you generate the circle how accurate is when displayed in the static image?